# Email to Custom Object?

Tags: email

Is there any way to send a standard PDF to have it assigned to a Custom Object and not use an EmailHandler?

Use Case -

- Email is generated with PDF, can customise the generation to include anything we want (eg. Salesforce ID) in the subject

  - Email is sent to SFDC email
  - PDF is attached to record, with lookup to Customer Account

**Any way this is possible without using an email handler?(code)**

Thanks!

Comment: I have investigated using Email to Salesforce, but this doesn't allow to custom objects, good suggestion to use flow below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this without a handler, though you might be able to use Email to Salesforce and then use a flow or process builder to move/copy the attachment that's created to the relevant custom object.

Comment: Ok great, I hadn't thought of using Flow... I'll investigate.